# Reena and the doors. How many?

Tags: logical-deduction, story

**Caution: You are entering a boring adventure zone**

You need to follow Reena's morning routine and answer the question:

How many doors did Reena physically open? (Total number of times she opened doors)

> It was Sunday and Reena decided to do some chores. She cleared the
>   sink by putting the dishes in the dishwasher. She also cleaned the
>   microwave and the oven with a napkin. She took out a mug from a
>   cabinet and a tea bag from another and made herself a cup of tea in
>   the microwave. She liked her Tea with milk (which she got from the
>   fridge). She threw the old tea bag in the trash can in a cabinet under
>   the sink. Then she decided to do her laundry. The laundry room was on
>   the ground floor of her Apartment Complex (not on the first floor
>   where her place was). So she prepared for that time. Got her dirty
>   laundry from her closet, remembered to pick up some seat covers from
>   her balcony.
>
> She was walking toward the elevator when she realized that it was
>   going to be a very hot day. So she turned back, went inside her
>   apartment and got herself an Ice Cream bar.
>
> She then took the elevator to the ground floor and went to the Laundry
>   room. She used her card key to get in. She liked the fact that all the
>   machines were new and front loading type. She started the washer.
>   Twenty to thirty minutes. She decided to go to the Courtyard in the
>   middle of the complex. Had to use her card key again to enter the
>   courtyard.
>
> The courtyard had a pool, vending, restrooms and lots of chairs. She
>   sat and ate her ice cream. Then she went to the courtyard rest room (nature calls).
>
> There was a small locked room at the courtyard where they had books,
>   games etc. She went in. Searched a book cabinet and got a paperback to
>   read.
>
> After a few minutes she went to the laundry room again. Washer was
>   done so she transferred the clothes to the dryer and started it.
>   Thirty more minutes!
>
> Back to the courtyard and the book reading. Now she was a little
>   thirsty so she walked to the vending machines and got herself a big
>   bottle of soda.
>
> In a few minutes she went to the laundry room to check on the dryer.
>   Clothes were not completely dry so needed to put another 10 minutes on
>   it. She had run out of quarters so she took the elevator and went in
>   her apartment. She kept lot of change in her fireproof safety box in
>   the closet. She took the quarters and this time took the stairs. Each
>   floor was door protected (card key again!).
>
> Into the laundry room. She started the dryer again and waited there
>   till it was done. She folded the laundry and took the elevator back to
>   her apartment. Put the laundry inside the closet and rest of the
>   change in the safety box.  DONE. Not really. She had brought the book
>   with her.
>
> So she rushed back to the stairs and the courtyard bookroom and replaced
>   the book in the book cabinet. She came back to her apartment via stairs. Now DONE.

How many doors did she open?

Please chose from

> A: Less than 60
>
> B: 61
>
> C: 62
>
> D: 63
>
> E: 66

Note

Only the following doors are spring loaded to close automatically

Apartment, balcony, laundry room, courtyard, restroom, stairs and bookroom

Assume the starting position of all doors to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: I think it is

> B, with 61 doors. This is also assuming that doors she opens she doesn't close.

But I might be overlooking something! I have highlighted the added rows. Following is a picture of my table.

> [image: [new table][]]

Comment: Great attempt. Missed out a few. Ones not directly mentioned. Plus leaving the safety box open is not very safe is it?

Comment: @DEEM - no, but it's not specifically called out she closed it! But now knowing that, I'll add it in, and also re-read for implied doors.

Comment: Guess you are right. That is why I put the Logical tag. But assumtions are fine too.

Comment: @DEEM, is this closer then?

Comment: Closer. Yet missing something.

Comment: @DEEM rot13(V'z nyfb nffhzvat gung pyrnavat gur zvpebjnir naq bira jvgu n ancxva qbrf abg zrna fur bcraf gur qbbef. Vf guvf nyfb na vapbeerpg nffhzcgvba?)

Comment: Yes It is incorrect.

Comment: Also remember: How many does she physically open?